# How to make buttons display their text in a label using one click event

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to have a click event that displays the text of buttons in a label in c#.

I want to write single code that will work for:

```
public button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e){ 
   label1.Text = button1.Text; 
}

public button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e){ 
   label2.Text = button2.Text;
}
```

Comment: Click event on? and can you provide some sample that you have tried so far?

Comment: What I'm trying to do, in essence is that; Instead of me repating similar code, I want to write single code that will work for;                                              public button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e){ label1.Text = button1.Text;   }.                                                    public button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e){ label2.Text;}.

Comment: may be have a function that accepts button and label as inputs and set text accordingly.

Comment: Edited my answer. Check if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

On a button click, you can handle setting text as below
you can add two buttons. Have same click events for both buttons.
Take help of parameter sender to get which button is clicked.

code (sender as Button) gives you all the details of clicked button.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.label1.Text = (sender as Button).Text;
    }
```

Comment: Yes but for more than 1 buttons.

Comment: Give same click event for both buttons. Parameters e and sender helps you to distinguish the buttons as this.label1.Text = (button1 as Button).Text;

Comment: seems like we both misunderstood the question in the first attempt. Since our updated answers are basically the same, I've deleted mine and upvoted yours.

Comment: Thanks Zohar. However the idea of having a dictionary was good. It would have helped others who might be looking for such answer.

Comment: I really appreciate both of you. You just saved me from unnecessary stress. Thanks a lot

Comment: @G_S I'm sure there are questions where my initial answer would fit. I'm even sure there are answers that have the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add a Button and a Label to the blank Form in a new project.

2) Double-click the Button.

This will generate the following Click event method...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

}
```

3) Put the following line of code in the button1_Click method body:

```
label1.Text = button1.Text;
```

4) Profit.